# Setting sample_variables property at runtime

Tags: variables, jmeter, runtime, output

Is there a way to specify a list of variables to be saved in the output file at runtime and not in jmeter.properties file?

I am currently specifying the list of variables to be saved in sample_variables, in jmeter.properties file, but this does not allow specifying different set of output variables for each JMeter script, unless I keep updating jmeter.properties file.

Answer (score 2):

You can pass `sample_variables` (as well as any other property) via `-J` command line argument like:

```
jmeter -Jsample_variables=foo -n -t script1.jmx
jmeter -Jsample_variables=bar,baz -n -t script2.jmx
```

Also, as per [Managing Properties](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#properties) chapter of JMeter User manual:

> When you need to modify jmeter properties, ensure you **don't modify jmeter.properties file**, instead copy the property from jmeter.properties and modify its value in user.properties file.

See [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization) article for comprehensive information on different JMeter properties types and ways of working with them

Comment: how to set the values at runtime(best in customized sampler)? i mean not the `foo` itself, but the **value** of foo.

Comment: Don't hijack the 7-years-old threads with comments which are absolutely unrelated to the original question. You should [ask your own question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) instead. As an exception: use [JMeterVariables](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html) class. For example like: `org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterContextService.getContext().getVariables().put("foo","bar");` More information on this and other JMeter API classes: [Top 8 JMeter Java Classes You Should Be Using with Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-java-classes)

Comment: thanks, exactly what i have been looking for several days! unfortunately i'm now unable to post question due to connection timeout to various js files (blocked from china).

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of the way to change sample_variables at runtime. The only workaround I know of is to have BeanShell Listener (or alternatively one of the programmable sampler/pre-/post-processors), which writes into its own file. E.g.:

```
String filename = "myfile.txt";

String message = "At " + System.currentTimeMillis() + " data is " + vars.get("myVar");

FileOutputStream f = new FileOutputStream(filename, true);
PrintStream p = new PrintStream(f); 
this.interpreter.setOut(p); 
print(message);
f.close();
```

You can also add conditions when the variable should be saved (e.g. only after specific sampler or only when the value have changed). From my experience the solution with BeanShell Listener is not expensive resources-wise, since it will be 1 thread regardless of number of running threads. Solution with programmable pre-/post-processor is usually more expensive, unless you only save variables rarely.